# Angular2 & RC5: How should my AppComponent look like now?

Tags: angular

That's the **new app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

import { AboutModule } from './+about/about.module';
import { HomeModule } from './+home/home.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), AboutModule, HomeModule, SharedModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

that's the **old AppComponent**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { Config, NavbarComponent, ToolbarComponent } from './shared/index';

/**
 * This class represents the main application component. Within the @Routes annotation is the configuration of the
 * applications routes, configuring the paths for the lazy loaded components (HomeComponent, AboutComponent).
 */
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavbarComponent, ToolbarComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Environment config', Config);
  }
}
```

In this Article (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html) you can read in chapter 5. Cleanup:

For RC5, you **can** leave your components, directives and pipes in the directives and pipes properties of your @Component metadata. **In fact**, we automatically **hoist (add) them to the NgModule** to which they belong.

### **Question:**

What do I have to remove here (AppComponent)?

**Or:**

What do I have to move from AppComponent to AppModule?

EDIT: All the files (components, configurations, etc,..) you can see in this seed here: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **RC.5** you should not place any *components / pipes / directives* into your @Component. Every of them you have to add into `declarations` array of your module.

So change your *AppComponent* into:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
```

And your *AppModule* into:

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), AboutModule, HomeModule, SharedModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [AppComponent, NavbarComponent, ToolbarComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
```

Every *component / directive / pipe* from module declarations array will be available **for each component**, which belongs to this module, so you do not have to worry about @Component directives array anymore.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly: Angular2 identifies pipes/directives/... automatically. All of them are to be placed into the declaration in my AppModule and they would be injected in case of necessity?

Comment: Yes, every of them will be injected, where it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those `directives` from your AppComponent.

You could add them to the NgModule's `declarations`.

The `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` isn't needed anymore!

Comment: Will I need to add `whatever.module.ts` for each component? Where should I place the pipes?

Comment: Would you take the files above as a basis and modify them regarding your answer? Thank you very much,..